# Chrome debugger continues to run with no breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome

Opening the chrome debugger on YouTube results in the debugger going crazy, looping over, various js files.

A video of it happening:
https://youtu.be/3JEWNzltQ1U

So far I've reset the debugger settings, re installed chrome, removed all breakpoints, removed all extensions and I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP discovered that the issue was not a computer-related problem people here could diagnose, or replicate other than by chance.  Cats walking on the keyboard would also be off-topic.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

just fixed it, turns out i had something lying on my second keyboard which was pushing the f8 key down.